# Bundles: wrong tax class when using fixed price

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, tax-class

I am facing exactly same problem as stated in https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/30204

I am looking for an optimal solution for that. I am using Avalra Avatax for tax calculation with Magento Version 2.3

I want Tax to be calculated based on the tax classes defined against each bundle line item

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this is to enable the dynamic price option when you creating the bundle product.

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/catalog/product-create-bundle.html#step-3-complete-the-required-settings

When you creating a bundle with a dynamic price then the price of the product is defined only from the options (products) you will add to it and the tax rule that each product has.

If you not use the dynamic price and add a custom price, then the system asks you to add a tax rule on the custom price and that overrides the tax of the options (products) that the bundle has.

I hope it helps